# WifiManager, disableNetwork() always returns false in Oreo

Tags: android, wifimanager

This is my code, The return value is always false. I have 'Location' permission enabled.
i am using this code to programatically connect to a different network(OPEN)[code is not given here. I am using enableNetwork() and reconnect()]. But, then phone automatically connects back to the previous network. 
This issue is observed in google pixel, v8.1.0. I have checked in android v7. works fine.

```
    WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) context.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
                List<WifiConfiguration> configurations = wifiManager.getConfiguredNetworks();
                for (WifiConfiguration config : configurations) {
                    Log.d("bhargav","SSID "+config.SSID);
//here it always returns false.
                        LibreLogger.d(this,"Disabling "+config.SSID+", result -> "+wifiManager.disableNetwork(config.networkId));

                }
```

Comment: from doc: *Applications are not allowed to disable networks created by other applications.* - are you sure that your app created this  network?

Comment: Selvin,i am using this code to programatically connect to a different network(OPEN). But, then phone automatically connects back to the previous network. So, i thought disabling network will solve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

When attempting to disable networks external to the application on Oreo the following error is prompted:

`E/WifiConfigManager: UID XXXX does not have permission to update configuration "SSID"`

Check [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49363190/oreo-wifi-connectivity) answers for more details.